# Visual Studio 2015 Package Extension,referenced dll not copied

Tags: roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

Hi I use roslyn Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Csharp dlls in my vs2015 extension,I upgraded my visual studio extension project to visual studio 2013 to 2015. but only My roslyn dll's are not copied when I want to install extension.My target framework is still same (.net 4.5.0). and I check nuget.org to new roslyn dlls ,Supported version looks same.I try to upgrade my roslyn versions but result is same.
If I manually copy to extension path roslyn dlls that time myextension is working.
Is there any Idea about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In visual studio 2015 vsix projects some dlls like Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll not copied to extension path.You can add

```
<ForceIncludeInVSIX>true</ForceIncludeInVSIX>
```

tag inside your reference tag  like.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.dll, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <ForceIncludeInVSIX>true</ForceIncludeInVSIX>
</Reference>
```

For details you can check this site...
http://comealive.io/Forcing-DLLs-To-Vsix/

Answer (score 2):

Roslyn is included with Visual Studio; you should not include Roslyn DLLs in your VSIX.

If you do, you may get lots of strange errors from loading a different copy of the DLLs.

Comment: Occasionally it's useful. For example if you want to ship the DLLs in a VSIX that also targets VS 2013. That said, people should definitely be aware of the risks.

Comment: agree it's part of VS 2015, however, when I created an extension in VS 2017, using Roslyn NuGet packages, VS 2015 does not see them.  Frustrating.

Comment: @Karl: You need to reference the lowest version of Roslyn / VS that you want your extension to support.

Comment: @SLaks OK makes sense.  I'll spin up a VM, install VS 2015 and see what version of Roslyn that is installed and give this a go.